# ruamel - block_seq_indent and indent

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have been struggling with getting my YAML file with correct indentation after using `yaml.round_trip_dump`. I am trying to figure what is the difference between `block_seq_indent` and `indent`. Couldn't really find anything useful in the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indent` is the normal indent that ruamel.yaml inherited from PyYAML. It affects both mapping keys and sequences elements. For sequences that means it doesn't affect  the hash ('-') before a sequence element.

So if you run:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

d = dict(a=1, b=[1, 2, {3: [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]}], c=dict(d=1, e=2))

ruamel.yaml.safe_dump(d, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, explicit_start=True)
ruamel.yaml.safe_dump(d, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, indent=4, explicit_start=True)
```

The output will be:

```
---
a: 1
b:
- 1
- 2
- 3:
  - 3.1
  - 3.2
  - 3.3
c:
  d: 1
  e: 2
---
a: 1
b:
-   1
-   2
-   3:
    -   3.1
    -   3.2
    -   3.3
c:
    d: 1
    e: 2
```

If you also provide `block_seq_indent` you can do:

```
ruamel.yaml.safe_dump(d, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, indent=4, 
                  block_seq_indent=3, explicit_start=True)
```

to get:

```
a: 1
b:
   - 1
   - 2
   - 3:
       - 3.1
       - 3.2
       - 3.3
c:
    d: 1
    e: 2
```

To have even more control you should use the new `ruamel.yaml` API where you can do:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=3, sequence=5, offset=2)
yaml.explicit_start = True
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

to get:

```
a: 1
b:
  -  1
  -  2
  -  3:
       -  3.1
       -  3.2
       -  3.3
c:
   d: 1
   e: 2
```

i.e. you can use `offset` to position the dash within the spaces that are the indent for the sequence elements.

This is documented [here](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detail.html#indentation-of-block-sequences)

Comment: Thanks for providing a clear explanation. For some reason, I am not able to import YAML(). This is what I am doing: `import ruamel.yaml yml =ruamel.yaml.YAML()`. I get this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'YAML'`

Comment: Also, while using block_seq_indent=3, why do we not have spacing between the "hyphen" and the sequence values?

Comment: What version of ruamel.yaml do you use? The `yml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()`  construct requires `ruamel.yaml>0.14`. You should provide a complete question (and not a comment), including code and output wrt to spacing.

Comment: regarding the spacing, it was in reference to the answer you provided, the third output to be specific. Sorry if it wasn't clear earlier. Thanks

Comment: It is still not clear: I have a space between the hyphen and the element in all my output examples (it would not be a YAML sequences otherwise). You write "why do we not have spacing", that doesn't make sense and cannot refer to any of my output.